# Remove/change red underline in columns

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor CSV mode shows a red underline to fill the remainder of a column when a cell's text is not wide enough. Does anyone know how to either remove or change this?[Example of red underline buffering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWk4c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to **Properties for Current Configuration** (or **All Configurations**) on the **Tools** menu, select the **Character Check** page, and clear the **Warn Control Characters** option.